# How do I calculate the gradient of the hinge loss function?

Tags: neural-networks, objective-functions, backpropagation, math, gradient-descent

With reference to the research paper entitled [Sentiment Embeddings with Applications to Sentiment Analysis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7296633), I am trying to implement its sentiment ranking model in Python, for which I am required to optimize the following hinge loss function:

$$\operatorname{loss}_{\text {sRank}}=\sum_{t}^{T} \max \left(0,1-\delta_{s}(t) f_{0}^{\text {rank}}(t)+\delta_{s}(t) f_{1}^{\text {rank}}(t)\right)$$

Unlike the usual mean square error, I cannot find its gradient to perform backpropagation.

How do I calculate the gradient of this loss function?

Comment: You will either need to contact the authors and hope at least one responds with the equation or you need to calculate it yourself.  The following article might help you: https://twice22.github.io/hingeloss/

Answer (score 1):

Hinge loss is difficult to work with when the derivative is needed because the derivative will be a piece-wise function. `max` has one non-differentiable point in its solution, and thus the derivative has the same. This was a very prominent issue with non-separable cases of SVM (and a good reason to use ridge regression).

Here's a slide (Original source from [Zhuowen Tu](https://sites.google.com/site/ucsdfall2018cogs118a/calendar-notes), apologies for the title typo):
[image: SVM Hinge Loss equation and derivative]

Where hinge loss is defined as `max(0, 1-v)` and `v` is the decision boundary of the SVM classifier. More can be found on [the Hinge Loss Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_loss).

As for your equation: you can easily pick out the `v` of the equation, however without more context of those functions it's hard to say how to derive. Unfortunately I don't have access to the paper and cannot guide you any further...

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the earlier answer that this is difficult to calculate. If we have the function
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}}  \max \{0, 1 - d(t) \, y(t, \theta)\}
\end{align*}
the gradient with respect to $\theta$ is
\begin{align*} 
& \sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}}g(t) \\
& g(t) := \begin{cases} 
 0 & \text{ if }1 - d(t) y(t, \theta) < 0 \\ 
 -d(t)\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \text{ otherwise} \\ 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Theoretically this is ok, it just means that the gradient is not continuous. However, the objective is still continuous assuming that $d$ and $y$ are both continuous.

In practice, it's not a problem either. Any automatic differentiation software (tensorflow, pytorch, jax) will handle something like this automatically and correctly.