# What is the gradient of a non-linear SVM with respect to the input?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, gradient-descent, support-vector-machine

The objective function of an SVM is the following:

$$J(\mathbf{w}, b)=C \sum_{i=1}^{m} \max \left(0,1-y^{(i)}\left(\mathbf{w}^{t} \cdot \mathbf{x}^{(i)}+b\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{w}^{t} \cdot \mathbf{w}$$
where

- $\mathbf{w}$ is the model's feature weights and $b$ is its bias parameter
- $\mathbf{x}^{(i)}$ is the $i^\text{th}$ training instance's feature vector
- $y^{(i)}$ is the target class ($-1$ or $1$) for the $i^\text{th}$ instance
- $m$ is the number of training instances
- $C$ is the regularisation hyper-parameter

And if I was to use a kernel, this would become:

$$J(\mathbf{w}, b)=C \sum_{i=1}^{m} \max \left(0,1-y^{(i)}\left(\mathbf{u}^{t} \cdot \mathbf{K}^{(i)}+b\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^{t} \cdot \mathbf{K} \cdot \mathbf{u}$$

where the kernel can be the Gaussian kernel:

$$K(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v})=e^{-\gamma\|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^{2}}$$

How would I go about finding its gradient with respect to the input?

I need to know this as to then apply this to a larger problem of a CNN with its last layer being this SVM, so I can then find the gradient of this output wrt the input of the CNN.

Comment: if by `max` you mean the actual maximum between two values, you may be in trouble since the gradient of the maximum is not [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) and hence not differentiable. So you can only compute the gradient as long as you have `1-yy_pred !=0`.

Comment: I found some work done on this here: http://www.ecmlpkdd2013.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/527.pdf
They talk about something similar in Section 3.1. Does it hold any weight with what I want to do?

Comment: @FeedMeInformation Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: See also https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/8281/2444.

Comment: Have you found the solution/answer to this problem/question? If yes, feel free to write it below. If not, I will consider starting a bounty on this post, if you still need an answer.